# How to test Trivial Drive example on a phone

Tags: in-app-purchase

I need to put in-app payments into my app. There are two problem areas at present.

1. Get the TrivialDrive Example app so I can run it on my phone correctly and recompile and install it easily.
2. Discover the structure of the TrivialDrive app and pick the parts that are relevant to me.

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio 12.5 and  Java

The key feature of testing in-app payments is that, although you need to publish the app in (at least Internal Testing) google Play, you can in fact side-load newer builds directly to your device. So it needs to exist in the Google Play app store but subsequent builds can be tested on your device without uploading it to Play.Google

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oPHyYYWpcfTyXjideWhicAkd1R1N1OwSsPi1xHILFBM/edit?usp=sharing

This document explains straightforwardly the steps to get to debugging on your phone using logcat.